# How to order the items of a DynamoDB table in AWS console?

Tags: sorting, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When I view the items of a DynamoDB table in the console, they always seem to be in a completely arbitrary order - this happens even if I specify a sort key. Can someone explain me this?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDb stores data physically based on Hash of partition key and since DynamoDb is a managed cloud service this Hash function is not clear. The output of hash function defines which node would store an item.Then within that node DynamoDb stores items by Sort key. 
Here is an example: if DynamoDb internal Hash function produces values between 1 to 100 and if it has 5 nodes then any item that hash of its partition key is between 1 to 20 will go to node 1, then any item with hash of its partition key being from 21 to 40 will go to node 2 and so on. 
So what you see in the console are items first sorted by Hash of partition key (and Hash function is unclear) and then sorted by sort key.